# JS import: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript

tools.js:

```
function someFunction() {
  console.log(1 + 1);
}

export { someFunction };
```

main.js

```
window.onload = function() {
  import { someFunction } from 'tools';
};
```

index.html:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/tools.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/main.js "></script>
```

And yet I get the error on the subject. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use `import` statements outside the top lines of your file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)s always have to be on the global scope:

```
 import { someFunction } from 'tools.js';

 window.onload = function() {
   //...  
  };
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas, but even if my main.js file has a single line with the import statement, I still get the error.

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla it also needs to be `type="module"`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts the main.js right? Because did that and solved the problem. I also had to specify tools.js as  the module name, not just tools. Thanks. This will be very hard because both, you and Jonas have answered!